# Simple javascript recursive function returns more values than actually exist?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am practicing recursion and have written this function:

```
var bigArray = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', {a:'e'}]]]];
var results = [];

function bagger293(bigArray){
  for (var item in bigArray){
    if (Array.isArray(bigArray[item])){
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    }
     else if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object'){
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    }else{
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
    }
  }
}

bagger293(bigArray);
console.log(results);
```

I simply want the function to push any single value to an array, and search deeper if it is an object or array. Oddly, my function returns this:

`[ 'a',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'd',
  'e',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'd',
  'e',
  'b',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'd',
  'e',
  'c',
  'd',
  'e',
  'd',
  'e' ]`

I assume it is because of my way of specifying

`bigArray[item]` but don't know why exactly.

expected result:

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

Comment: I don't even see how this is any good in context of recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an `else`. Once you've spotted an array, stop trying to do other things with it.

```js
var bigArray = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', { a: 'e' }]]]];
var results = [];

function bagger293(bigArray) {
  for (var item in bigArray) {
    if (Array.isArray(bigArray[item])) {
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    } 
    else if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object') {   // <--
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    } 
    else {
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
    }
  }
}

bagger293(bigArray);
console.log(results);
```

On the other hand, since all arrays are objects, you can just test for `'object'`:

```js
var bigArray = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', { a: 'e' }]]]];
var results = [];

function bagger293(bigArray) {
  for (var item in bigArray) {
    if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object') {
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    } 
    else {
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
    }
  }
}

bagger293(bigArray);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: I was slightly faster. :o

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an else. Since an array is an object as well, your code starts the recursion twice.

This is working:

```
function bagger293(bigArray){
  for (var item in bigArray){
    if (Array.isArray(bigArray[item])){
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    }else if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object'){
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    }else{
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All arrays are objects. No need to check both `Array.isArray` and `typeof == 'object'`.

```js
var bigArray = ['a', ['b', ['c', ['d', {a:'e'}]]]];
var results = [];
(function bagger293(bigArray) {
  for (var item in bigArray)
    if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object')
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    else
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
})(bigArray);
console.log(results);
```